# IEEEtranSN + natbib and @masterthesis

Tags: natbib, ieeetran, thesis, ieee-style

I'm using `natbib` along with `bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}`.  Everything works great, but when I'm trying to add an @masterthesis entry, I get the following warning:

> Warning--entry type for "tarzan2013" isn't style-defined.

I have tried changing @masterthesis for @thesis and I still get the same warning.

I've looked in the [IEEEtrans_bst_HOWTO](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf), and it seems @masterthesis is supported.  Why am I having this warning then?

My entry looks like this:

```
@masterthesis{tarzan2013,
  title={My monkey and some other stuff},
  author={Tarzan de la Vega},
  year={2012},
  school={The jungle and others}
}
```

Comment: Stupid thing:  It's "MasterSthesis", not "masterthesis".  Please close